# Как динамично отображать директивы на angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

```
<body>
<login-content></login-content>
<main-content></main-content>
</body>
```

сейчас тупо присутствуют на странице оба html-шаблона, но как сделать так, чтобы можно было по клику подгружать, например , заменив и чтобы angular сразу все распарсил и без ошибки отработал?

Comment: что значит _присутствуют на странице оба html-шаблона_? что значит _можно было по клику подгружать_? подгружать что?

Comment: сейчас контент отображает и тот, и тот. Мне нужно, если у нас нет куков, тогда login-content отображайся, если есть тогда main-content

Comment: можно использовать `ng-if`, можно воспользоваться роутером

Comment: сейчас вопрос слишком широк, стоит его конкретизировать добавив [mcve] как это есть сейчас с комментариями как бы хотелось